# Opposite result views with comparison

Tags: views

I'm trying to achieve this...

A Views that shows as result the names of people who do not appear in list of published nodes of a content type. 
(List of people who will not attend an event...)

Configuration:

Content Type Event:
Person field, supports adding more than one (multivalue), using autocomplete.
This field is of the entity reference type and displays the list of possible names obtained from the result of a view.

Assuming that the list of persons is total A B C and D.

I create 1 node of event type
And I included people A and B.

The result of the views should be...
People C and D.

Is this achievable?

Answer (score 0):

Previous setup:
Create a new computed field for the content type where you want to work:
Extract the names from the multivalue field (entity referenced field)

```
foreach ($entity->field_campos as $field) {
} 
foreach ($entity->field_campos as $field) {
} 
foreach ($field as $index => $valores) {
$terminos[] = $valores['value'];
}
$item2 = field_collection_item_load_multiple($terminos, $reset = FALSE);

$referenced_titles = array(); 
foreach ($item2 as $indice => $values) {
  $referenced_node = node_load($values->field_nombre_2['und'][0]['target_id']);
$entity_field[]['value'] = $referenced_node->title;
}
```

Now that every node from this content type has a special field for extracting the values in a more "flat" way we can compare two views.
The first with the name list (usually partial) and the second, a views containing the full name list.

```
<?php
$result = views_get_view_result('calendari_intern', 'nombres');
$result2 = views_get_view_result('nom_expedients', 'entityreference_1');
```

First load both arrays. The first one, is the view result with partial name list. The second, is the view of the full name list.

Extract and create a new array saving only the names from the arrays:

```
foreach ($result2 as $index => $val) {
$expedient[] = $val->node_title;
}
```

Do the same in the other one:

```
foreach ($result as $index => $values) {
$entidades[] = $values->_field_data[nid][entity];
}
foreach ($entidades as $indice => $valores) {
if ($valores->field_nombres[und] !=NULL)
$casi[] = $valores->field_nombres[und];
}
foreach ($casi as $indice2 => $valores2) {
 foreach ($valores2 as $indice3 => $valores3) {
if ($valores3["value"] != NULL) {
$misnombres[] = $valores3["value"];
}
}
}
```

Then compare the arrays with array_diff function.

```
$diferencia = array_diff($expedient, $misnombres);
echo '<pre>';
print_r ($diferencia);
echo  '</pre>';
?>
```